# Where to find / How to install missing imjournal shared object file (/usr/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.so) for rsyslog

Tags: debian, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I am playing around with logging using rsyslog and journald and I wanted to see how effective the `imjournal` module was. So I added `$ModLoad imjournal` to my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and restarted rsyslog. After restarting rsyslog I started getting errors suggesting that `imjournal` is missing on my system:

```
could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.so', dlopen:
  /usr/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.so:
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
```

I tried searching `apt` and asking The Internet but didn't find any instructions on where to find it and/or how to install it.

```
$ apt-cache policy imjournal
N: Unable to locate package imjournal
```

Where can I find the missing `/usr/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.so`? How do I install it? Or do I need a newer version of rsyslog, systemd or Debian to do so?

---

**Note: I'm running Debian 8 with systemd version 215 and rsyslog 8.4.2**

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
$ rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.4.2, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
$ apt-cache policy rsyslog
rsyslog:
  Installed: 8.4.2-1+deb8u2
  Candidate: 8.4.2-1+deb8u2
  Version table:
 *** 8.4.2-1+deb8u2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/stat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my raspberry pi, the 8.24.0 version changelog suggests you won't have `imjournal` in your release:

> Version 8.4.3 [v8-stable] 2014-10-??
>
> - bugfix: imjournal did not build properly.
>   The build succeeded, but the module did not load due to a type in
>   a support function name, which kept unresolved during load.

and the changelog.Debian:

> rsyslog (8.8.0-1) experimental; urgency=medium
>
> - Enable support for reading from and writing to the systemd journal
>   directly via the imjournal and omjournal module.